# the application wrapper must end in .app when upload to AppStore

Tags: ios, upload

when i upload my app th AppStore:

The application wrapper must end in .app. /var/folders/92/q8js8qtx3
bgq94ncd149rv000gp/Card_Production_Ver1.1.0_GREE/3464sangokushikidist.mobileprovision
is invalid.

3465sangokushikidist.mobileprovision is invalid?

many thanks!

Comment: You upload an .app file to the app store, not a .mobileprovision file (which is used to "sign" the app). It might be helpful to revise / edit your question to explain how you are archiving & uploading your app to the app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to be using your Distribution Profile (take a look to the Provision Portal to see how to create them) when Archiving your project.
Then you can submit your application from that very XCode screen that pops up when the Archive has finalized.
If you're using a zipper to zip you ipa, you may want to read [this post](http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2012/03/26/application-launcher-error-application-wrapper-must-end-app).

Hope it helps.

Cheers!